# VBA Corrupt file?

Tags: excel, vba

I've been running code to update a "STATS" sheet from a copy of "9 TEAM CALCS" sheet. I have a macro that creates a "working copy" of the 9 TEAMS CALCS sheet into a new workbook and once the working copy is completed I press a button to update the stats back to the main database "STATS" sheet.  It has been working great but now the only update it will do to the stats page is the "Date" (statsDate_T1P1.Value = Date).  From the main workbook if I do not do the working copy it will update all the stats just fine. I've quadruple checked the workbook file name and I do have the main workbook open when doing the update.

```
Private Sub update_player_stats_Click()
Dim STATS As Worksheet
Dim CALCS As Worksheet
Dim players_stats As Range
Dim LastRow As Long

Set STATS = Workbooks("Results-Rev-6-2").Worksheets("STATS")
Set CALCS = Workbooks("Results-Rev-6-2").Worksheets("9 TEAM CALCS")

' TEAM 1, PLAYER 1
Dim statsPlayer_T1P1 As Range
Dim statsDate_T1P1 As Range
Dim statsTeamWin_T1P1 As Range
Dim statsFront9_T1P1 As Range
Dim statsBack9_T1P1 As Range
Dim statsQuota_T1P1 As Range

Set statsPlayer_T1P1 = STATS.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
Set statsDate_T1P1 = STATS.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 1)
Set statsTeamWin_T1P1 = STATS.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 2)
Set statsFront9_T1P1 = STATS.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 3)
Set statsBack9_T1P1 = STATS.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 4)
Set statsQuota_T1P1 = STATS.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 6)

statsPlayer_T1P1.Value = CALCS.Range("B8").Value
statsDate_T1P1.Value = Date
statsTeamWin_T1P1.Value = CALCS.Range("B9").Value
statsFront9_T1P1.Value = CALCS.Range("E9").Value
statsBack9_T1P1.Value = CALCS.Range("F9").Value
statsQuota_T1P1 = CALCS.Range("D9").Value

End Sub
```

Comment: I suggest you set a breakpoint and step through the code

Comment: Stepped through it and it does nothing except the date.  No errors at all.  As mentioned it was working fine until the last scores update and it just didn't work anymore.  That's why I feared a corrupt file or something.  I have been making upgrades in other parts of the main workbook but had nothing to do with the scores and stats sheets.

Comment: As you calculate the destination row for every field separately: Maybe you have some data somewhere down the sheet? Check `statsPlayer_T1P1.address` in the debugger. I guess it's a good idea to calculate the row only once and store it in a variable.

Comment: Is this your entire subroutine? What is the purpose of `LastRow`? I feel like something's missing here...

Comment: I commented out both of player_stats and LastRow.  There were from when I was first started writing the code and just hadn't commented them out.  They are now.

Comment: The T1P1 is just the first team and player 1.  There are 9 more teams of four so 36 sets of stats total on one sheet.  I only show T1P1 here because the rest is identical with the exception of cell differences.  This all worked beautifully until yesterday and then it didn't.

Comment: Just to reiterate, it works perfectly in the main workbook.  It's when I make the "working copy" in a new book that it doesn't work when it did before.

Comment: @funthomas The CALCS sheet has formulas that creates the value for what is being copied to the STATS sheet.  Once a days round of scores is entered, checked and published on our web then I copy each players stats to the STATS sheet so eventually I can provide detailed reports on each players scores and winnings.  At this link you can see an image of the CALCS sheet.  https://www.macdillmag.com/forum/macdill-mens-golf-league/saturday-sep-26-2020-results